# EF CORE: How to modify owned collection on entity

Tags: concurrency, updates, ef-core-3.1

I have entity "MyEntity" with a list of owners. Each owner object has 3 properties - Id, type, link.
In the configuration, I am mapping this like owned object.

```
builder.OwnsMany(a => a.Owner, ownershipBuilder =>
        {
            ownershipBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Link);
            ownershipBuilder.Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired();
            ownershipBuilder.Property(x => x.Type)
                .HasConversion(t => t.ToString(),
                value => (MyType) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyType), value))
                .IsRequired();
        });
```

Now, when I try to update this collection of owners, I got `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`

The flow of update is:

1. find parent entity by its ID
2. add owner into the list
3. call Update method on the dbContext and SaveChanges.

After calling savechanges I got mentioned exception.

Any idea here?

THX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it,

I am generating Link (Owner entity) in code and this is key in table also. Thus I must use ValueGeneratedNever in the entity configuration.

```
ownershipBuilder.Property(x => x.Link).ValueGeneratedNever().IsRequired();
```

Problem solved.